# Random Forest: Histograms for the Margins for Different Outcome Classes

Tags: r, random-forest, histogram

I am working with random forests (in R).

Is there a way to plot a histogram of the margins of different response outcomes?

I have a categorical response variable with three outcomes, and I want to graph a historgram of the margins for each of these outcomes. Is this possible?

I know that

```
hist(margin(rf, response))
```

is a histogram of the margins, but with three outcomes how do I know which outcome it chose to be True? And how do I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use this example with 3 classes:

```
library(randomForest)
data=iris
data$response = factor(data$Species)
data$Species = NULL

rf = randomForest(response  ~ .,data=data)
```

The class is actually in the name of the margin output:

```
head(margin(rf,data$response))
setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa 
     1      1      1      1      1      1
```

We can assign a color to the different classes:

```
COLS = c("#00468BFF","#ED0000FF","#42B540FF")
names(COLS) =unique(data$response)
MAR = sort(margin(rf,data$response))
plot(as.numeric(MAR),col=COLS[names(MAR)],pch=20,ylab="margin")
legend("bottomright",fill=COLS,names(COLS))
```

[image]

If you can use ggplot2, then you can do this and the histogram easily:

```
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(margin=MAR,label=names(MAR),index=1:length(MAR))
ggplot(df,aes(x=index,y=MAR,col=label)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=MAR,fill=label)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~label)
```

[image]